# cleartext HTTP traffic to not permitted

Tags: php, android

На 9ом андроиде запрос в php даёт ошибку

> cleartext HTTP traffic to not permitted

Все  пишут, что решается это добавлением в манифест разрешения 
`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` (другие схожие решения также выносят приложение)
Но в этом случае приложение падает без каких либо ошибок. Как можно отыскать или проблему или решение этого?
Спасибо.

Лог: https://gist.github.com/kofnal/b26ba7cb95ac48541742eff81fb55509

> --------- beginning of crash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
>       Process: market5.project.market5, PID: 10342
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion;
>           at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109)
>           at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
>           at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/market5.project.market5-Xv8APaI1vVwS-UfQyuB5OA==/base.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/market5.project.market5-Xv8APaI1vVwS-UfQyuB5OA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/market5.project.market5-Xv8APaI1vVwS-UfQyuB5OA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/market5.project.market5-Xv8APaI1vVwS-UfQyuB5OA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/market5.project.market5-Xv8APaI1vVwS-UfQyuB5OA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/market5.project.market5-Xv8APaI1vVwS-UfQyuB5OA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/market5.project.market5-Xv8APaI1vVwS-UfQyuB5OA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/market5.project.market5-Xv8APaI1vVwS-UfQyuB5OA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/market5.project.market5-Xv8APaI1vVwS-UfQyuB5OA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/market5.project.market5-Xv8APaI1vVwS-UfQyuB5OA==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/market5.project.market5-Xv8APaI1vVwS-UfQyuB5OA==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/market5.project.market5-Xv8APaI1vVwS-UfQyuB5OA==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/market5.project.market5-Xv8APaI1vVwS-UfQyuB5OA==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/market5.project.market5-Xv8APaI1vVwS-UfQyuB5OA==/lib/arm,
>   /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>           at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109) 
>           at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96) 
>           at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112) 
>         Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm)
>   /data/app/market5.project.market5-Xv8APaI1vVwS-UfQyuB5OA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:101)
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:75)
>           at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
>           at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
>           at dalvik.system.DexPathList.(DexPathList.java:164)
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
>           at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.(PathClassLoader.java:64)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
>           at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
>           at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:766)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:849)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1090)
>           at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2563)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6176)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:241)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1807)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10342 SIG: 9

Comment: Лог можно и нужно публиковать прямо в вопросе - людям лень ходить по всяким ссылкам. И вы не выложили самое интересное - то что после `--------- beginning of crash`

Comment: Интернет разрешили в манифесте?

Comment: интернет разрешен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ex.ex.ex">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        >
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        ...
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: `<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />` - зачем эта строка, вы используете apache `HttpClient`? Бросьте эту затею - есть более удобные и современные решения. Или посмотрите внимательно это решение: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55121645 - есть у вас строка `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` в `build.gradle`?  И не пишите дополнения к вопросу в ответах - редактируйте сам вопрос.

Comment: Вчерашний вечер растаял на попытки решить вопрос как в https://stackoverflow.com/a/55121645 , а строка useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' в build.gradle отсутствует у меня. Сам не понял как оно работает, но работает и ладно пока. Все равно у меня сервер http, а не https...

Answer (score 0):

Интернет разрешаем в манифесте

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />`

и далее добавляем файл по пути

`**res** -> **xml** -> network_security_config.xml`

содержимое

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

под тегом `application` прописываем путь

```
 <application
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
>
```